# What should you do with channels when creating them?

Tags: java, reactor-netty

When creating with `HttpServer#doOnChannelInit`, it turned out that with each initial request a `Channel` is created once and I don’t understand what it is based on. Let me give you an example: Each time you visit the site, if the user is registered, a session is automatically created, respectively, this is one Channel, and all Http requests create a Channel. So, I had a question, on what basis are channels created one-time, whether they should be given automatic closing, and whether it would be better for each user who is currently using the web application to implement something like `Map<User, Channel>` which stores user channels through which all user requests will pass?

Comment: A channel is netty's abstraction for a request / connection (https://medium.com/@akhaku/netty-data-model-threading-and-gotchas-cab820e4815a for example), they aren't bound to users and probably shouldn't be in any kind of map. Your server should be able to respond to any request and mostly not be concerned which channel is involved (like in regular http servers you don't worry about the tcp connection)